# searching for and updating values within list using kdb+ Q

Tags: kdb

I am trying to complete the following on a list of integers: a:(1;2;3;4;5)

update all elements by adding there index? I tried `a+?[]` , `a+a[]`

check if numbers 2, 3 and 4 exist?

check how many odd numbers there are?

would anyone know a good source of learning for kdb q?

many thanks

Comment: I would recommend q for mortals - https://code.kx.com/q4m3/

Comment: Lining to correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002196/adding-indexes-to-elements-of-a-list-in-kdb

Answer (score 0):

1. create a table with an index

   t:([ind:til count a] a)

access index 1

```
t[1]

Key Value
a   2
```

2. location of 3 in a

   a?3

below will return count/length (5) so means it doesn't exist in the list

```
a?6
```

3. Number of odd numbers in a list

   sum(a mod 2)